# How to debug a total system lockup?

Tags: linux, freeze, hardware-failure

I’m running the latest version of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a powerful desktop PC. It works fine most of the time, but once in a while my system randomly runs into this weird lockup, described in more detail below. On some days it occurs every other hour, which is prone to data loss and gets very annoying. This has never happened to me running Microsoft Windows on the same PC (but I’m not using that OS very often).

Here is the situation described in more detail. I’m casually working on my PC, not running any intense calculations. All of a sudden the display freezes, including the mouse cursor. If I have any audio playback running, it will continue to run in a short loop for a few seconds before it completely stops. Magic SysRq keys will not work at that point! I have to kill my PC by holding down the power button. No automatic error report will be generated.

How does one even start analyzing the cause of this problem? It’s very difficult because of two reasons: 1. it’s intermittent, and 2. the system becomes completely unresponsive, not allowing for any command input.

Although the title of this question is fairly general, I would appreciate both general and specific tips.

---

Here is what I’ve tried already: I was running the two commands `sudo dmesg -Tw` and `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in a terminal emulator in the background. Neither of them was producing any output the moment the freeze happened.

Comment: By any chance a Ryzen CPU? Which version? What kernel version are you running (`uname -r`)?

Comment: @Fiximan No, my CPU is from Intel, specifically Core i7-10700K. My kernel version is `5.8.0-36-generic`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Intel here has the same problems as I expirenced with my Ryzen-based laptop.

General info: C-states are power saving modes of the CPU, enabled to reduce power consumption, but it looks like there are bugs when going into or leaving such a state. See [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051) (yes, very old). The higher the C-state, the more the CPU "sleeps".

Try the following: in `/etc/default/grub` change the line

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

to

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet intel_idle.max_cstate=5"
```

then run `update-grub` and reboot. If that still does not work, reduce the max. C-state to 1. Note that this means more power consumption.

There is also a [bugfix script from 2016](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=223851) which claims to only disable C6 (do not just run it, read it first). Take a look if you can find these files listed in the script `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/cpuidle/stateY/CZ*-BYT` and check their content.

Comment: Thank you kind sir for proposing this solution. Of course it will take a few days to confirm whether this fixes my problem. That discussion on Bugzilla you’ve linked is very interesting. I see my symptoms are the same as described in that bug report, so that makes me hopeful – at least it’s a strong indication that the problem is caused by the CPU, I guess.

Comment: I’m a bit confused because from what I read, they should have included a fix in kernel version 5.3 back in 2019 (and therefore the thread on Bugzilla is closed), but a few users are still reporting the same issue in later kernel versions. Was the alleged fix perhaps only working for certain CPU models? And if it turns out I’m affected by this very bug, do you know what is the best platform/thread where I should post my experience to assist the kernel developers?